# Requiring button press before calculations carried out and plot drawn in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have some code I am trying to write in Shiny.  This involves the following steps:
- choosing a date
- checking whether a valid input file exists for the date
- if a valid input file exists, pulling down remote time series ending on that date
- carrying out calculations
- plotting the result of the calculations

The date checking should be done reactively. However, the dime series pull down and calculations take some time.  I therefore want this to be done only with a button press.

I have most of this working.  However, whilst I can put the first instance of the calculation off until a button press using

```
    "if(input$run_shiny_risk==0){
    } else {
    #some code
    }
```

I can't stop it from calculating automatically on subsequent instances.  In other words, as soon as a valid date is chosen, calculations start automatically.  I have tried to isolate the calculations without success. I have also tried to isolate a dummy variable that is driven by the button value, but again no luck.  Here is what I have in terms of code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Risk Dashboard"),
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

  helpText("Effective date"),

  dateInput("shiny_end_date",
            label = "Date (yyyy-mm-dd):",
            value = "2018-12-31"),

  actionButton("run_shiny_risk",
               label = "Run risk report:"),

  textOutput("selected_var")

),

mainPanel(

  plotOutput("selected_var1")

)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

shiny_risk_test <- 0

output$selected_var <- renderText({

holdings_data_file <-paste(substr(input$shiny_end_date,3,4),substr(input$shiny_end_date,6,7),substr(input$shiny_end_date,9,10),"_Data.csv",sep="")
if(file.exists(holdings_data_file)){

  end_date <- input$shiny_end_date

  paste("You have selected", end_date)

} else {
  "No such file"
}
})

output$selected_var1 <- renderPlot({

holdings_data_file <-paste(substr(input$shiny_end_date,3,4),substr(input$shiny_end_date,6,7),substr(input$shiny_end_date,9,10),"_Data.csv",sep="")

if(file.exists(holdings_data_file)){

 if(input$run_shiny_risk==0){

   #this stops the chart from being drawn initially...

    } else {


    plot_data <- cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))        
    p<-plot(plot_data)

    p
    }

} else {       

} 
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, this works until the first click.  I can change dates between valid and invalid ones, and no chart is drawn until I hit the button.  Then, if I move to an invalid date, the chart vanishes, which is right.  But if I go back to a valid date, the chart appears again (and would be recalculated if I had the actual, lengthy code enclosed).  And code that just stops calculations until the button is pressed, not only the first time but in subsequent case, would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: have you looked into `isolate()`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried isolate on several blocks of code, and also on the dummy variable I've tried to use to track the number of button clicks, but I can't get the behaviour to change/work.

Comment: have a look at eventReactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in a previous application via the use of reactive values. Consider the following example:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output_staging <- reactiveValues()
  output_staging$title <- NA

  observeEvent(input$updateButton,{  update_title()  })

  update_title <- function(){
    output_staging$title <- paste0("random number ",runif(1))
  }

  output$title <- renderText(output_staging$title)

}
```

The `renderText` output looks at the reactive value stored in `output_staging$title`. Each time the button is clicked, an update function is called that replaces the reactive value.

Note that I could merge the function `update_title` and the `observeEvent` command. But having them separate gives me more flexibility.

In your context, I would recommend separating the data prep and the plot generation in order to use this method. You can use the reactive values at either place:

1. Button sends data to reactiveValue: data --> reactive --> make plot --> display plot
2. Button sends plot to reactiveValue: data --> make plot --> reactive --> display plot

But you don't need to use it at both.

Comment: Thank you - a version of this worked.  The key points were: creating output_staging as a reactiveValues object; putting the main code into observeEvent; passing the results from the observeEvent to (in the example) renderText.  I also used isolate within the observeEvent just to make sure...